# Products discount pinned at the top of the lists

Tags: 7, nodes, commerce, rules

I would like that when a product at a discount, it is "Pinned to the top of the lists" automatically.

And when a product does not have a discount, it is no longer "Pinned to the top of the lists".

How to do this with a rule?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Maybe you will be able to point me to this simple question, if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with a rule. Whether or not something is sticky depends on how Views sorts a list of products, and there is no sort handler that I'm aware of that would show discounted products first. The closest you could come to would be an extra field on your products that you set when you enable the discount to identify a discounted product. You would then be able to sort by that field value.

Comment: thank you. Do you know if this feature is expected (it would be very useful) ? Is there a module to do this ?

Comment: I don't intend to add it to the core of 1.x myself. It's hard to create a truly generic implementation of this to be honest. The simplest solution would be the field based solution I outlined.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I will use the flag module.